# error: illegal character: \65279 java android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn working with Android studio and I am relatively new in this field. So, I built this small application that actually just opens up the camera but then when I build the project, I am getting this annoying error which says "Error:(15, 33) error: illegal character: \65279" . I have done my research online and made sure that all my file encoding are in UTF-8 and still the error doesnt seem to go away. This is my java class.

```
package com.example.user.cameraapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;﻿



public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE =1;
    ImageView img;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        //Disable the button if the user has no camera
        if(!hasCamera()){
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCamera() {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    private void launchCamera(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Take a picture pass results to onActivityResult

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    }

    //If you want to return the image taken


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }
}
//The error points to the specific import 'import android.widget.ImageView;﻿

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.cameraapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about the first 3 bytes which have been added as BOM header. See: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23653934/UTF-8-java-file-dont-compile-correctly-because-of-BOM.html